# LoadLibrary never returning in visual studio 2013 c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

I have written a static library which depends on 3 librarys a.lib, b.lib, c.dll. Now i have written a test project and it works fine with this project. But there is another project which includes this static library in one of its dll say x.dll and later use this dll in project.

Now when project tries to load x.dll using LoadLibrary it never returns and keep on waiting. I have kept c.dll b.lib and a.lib all at the same location still its unable to load.
Tried using dependency walker but cant see much differnce with before and after including this library.

How should i go about identifying the problem?
Can i by any chance include every dependency in .lib? I felt since its the static library it should include all the dependencies in itself.
thanks in advance for your help.
The project is visual c++ in visual studio 2013.

Comment: Seeing your program deadlock on LoadLibrary() only ever has one explanation: you put too much code in your DllMain() entrypoint.  Google "dllmain loader lock" for basic help.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadLibrary` calls `DllMain()` of a DLL file. It is like a `main()` for DLL. There must be something deadlocked in `DllMain`.

Note: Sometimes there's no `DllMain` in DLL's code, but the compiler would automatically create one for initializing global variables with constructors, which could also lead to the problem.

To clarify, you could use `LoadLibraryEx` with `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` set. The flag will disable `DllMain` and disable loading dependencies. If it succeeds, the problem is in `DllMain`. (But you cannot use the DLL now, almost all modern DLLs behave incorretly without `DllMain`)

To debug, you could breakpoint on `Ntdll.LdrpCallInitRoutine`, `DllMain()` is called in this function.

Comment: Thanks Keyu. Indeed the problem looks to be with DllMain. I used LoadLibraryEx with DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES set and it was able to load the library. But how do i get rid of this issue? You said the DLL will be unusable with this.
Can i somehow compile my library in such a way that it works with LoadLibrary itself?

Comment: Yes you can. But you need to modify a lot of code. 1) you need to change your project type from static library to dynamic library. 2) mark all public functions, members, classes with dllexport descriptor and you may need to create an extra exports.def to clarify exported things. And recompile it. 3) link header file and lib (they are only reference to DLLs, unlike static ones) files to your project. 4) if you do need to use LoadLibrary instead of a lib file, you need to declare all exported functions as function pointer. And call GetProcAddress to fill them.

Comment: Besides, you can try using the 'unusable' dll. In very few times, it is ok to use.